# Error using JLayer library and running in command prompt

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I'm using JavaZOOM JLayer library and I built a small program that plays music. Here is the code:

```
import javazoom.jl.player.Player;
import java.io.FileInputStream;
public class Test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            FileInputStream fis = new FileInputStream(/*SONG PATH*/);
            Player player = new Player(fis); //<-- Here is the problem

            player.play();
        } catch(Exception e){
        }
    }
}
```

The code works when I use Intellij IDEA (I can hear the music), but when I try running on the command prompt, it throws the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: javazoom/jl/player/Player
at Test.main<Test.java:9>

Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: javazoom.jl.player.Player
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass<Unknown Source>
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass<Unkonwn Source>
at sun.misc.Launcer$AppClassLoader.loadClass<Unknown Source>
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass<Unknown Source>
... 1 more
```

I'm new using external libraries, so I don't know what is the problem...

P.S. I think it is a problem with the `CLASSPATH` variable, but I don't know to use it.

Answer (score 0):

When you compile your code using the command line with `javac`, you can set the `-classpath` option with the location of your external library.

So you could do something like `javac -classpath location\of\library class_to_compile`.

Oracle's documentation on the topic is very useful: http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/tools/windows/classpath.html

Comment: And which location should I put? I know where is it, but I don't know which directory. Should I put -classpath C:\Java Libraries\JLayer1.0.1\JLayer1.0.1 ?

Comment: Yes - try that and then add in the name of the file to compile after the classpath

Comment: I tried that but it says javac: invalid flag C:\Java Libraries\JLayer1.0.1\JLayer1.0.1\classes\javazoom\jl\player\Player.class

Comment: Try putting the location of the javazoom JAR instead.

Comment: The same thing again, javac: invalid flag C:\Java Libraries\JLayer1.0.1\JLayer1.0.1\classes 
Should I put the classes folder or what?

I'm doing the following: javac -classpath C:\Java Libraries\JLayer1.0.1\JLayer1.0.1\classes Test.java 

Is it right or am I wrong?

Comment: Sorry - that was bad wording on my part. Use the path to the JAR - something like .....\javazoom.jar.

Comment: It still doesn't work... the only thing that is a jar is "jl1.0.1". I tried C:\Java Libraries\JLayer1.0.1\JLayer1.0.1\jl1.0.1.jar but still nothing...

Comment: Try putting the path in quotation marks - it could be that the spaces in the directory name are causing problems.

Comment: I did this, i works but the problem is in the -classpath thing... I copied the javazoom library (copied all the folder) and pasted it in the folder that contains Test.java. Then I put javac Test.java, then java Test and worked.. But it's not very practical to copy all the time the javazoom library... Why is this happening?